# State Machine explanation

Tags: c++, command-line, operating-system, switch-statement, state

We are learning about State Machines in my Operating systems class this semester and I am struggling. This is a snippet from some code that we were provided. Could anyone possibly explain to me what it is doing or how the switches would be implemented? I have gone through the book without any luck and my teacher is unavailable this week. This is not an assignment but an ungraded exercise to help us understand how to implement states. Please help me!

```
/* Implements a state machine that parses the command line arguments, searching for switches and switch parameters.*/

int switches::getswitch()
{
while (true)                        // loop until a switch is        identified and returned
{
    int c = next();             // get next character to parse

    switch (state)                  // process the current state
    {
        case START:    //whats going on here?
        {
            sign = 0;

            if (c == END_S && index >= args.size())
                return END_S;
            switch (c)
            {
                case '/':
                    state = S_SWITCH;
                    break;
                default:
                    next_arg();
                    state = START;
                    break;
            }
            break;
        }

        // Add states here, what are the states that need to be implemented and how are they implemented?


    }
}
```

}

Comment: Before starting to write code for a state machine draw a diagram (nodes states, vertices are changes in state due to input).

Answer (score 1):

A state machine is just a way of approaching a problem in software or computer hardware. You break your design into a series of meaningful steps (called states), then transition from state to state depending on certain conditions. See the Wikipedia article on state machines for a [simple example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_machine#Example%3a_a_turnstile).

In this case, the current state is checked using a `switch` statement (a common approach). The code for each case does whatever specific task it needs to do for that state, then sets the next state. If you are confused about what `switch` statements do, see [this guide](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/).

Answer (score 1):

that's basically a polling loop (google for what it means). You have "c" wich is current input and is gathered by "next()".

At every loop you have just 2 informations:

-state (your current state)
-c  (your current input)

you have to track down with a state diagram all relevant cases. You have to switch "state" and inside every case you have to do proper handling of "c" (and of course you have to update the state if it has to be). optionally there are other things to do based on current input and state (for example the "next_arg()" call ).

How to implement new states? simply add more cases to the switch statement, of course first you need a good states diagram as reference.

Answer (score 0):

snake and ladder game will be simplest state diagram example. if you are in some state and the input is X and based on the input you can move the the next state ( up/down/horizontal) .

In your example it will equated to

Read the input
check the current position move the spaces
Case UP
     Do some action
Case DOWN
      Do some action

Hope this analogy helps you